# Displayed entities toggle at each zoom level on OpenLayers map

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, zoom, multi-polygon, debugging

I have a PostGIS table connected to my GeoServer in which I have published a layer of 80 multipolygon features. The multipolygons have very different sizes and are displayed correctly in the Openlayers map preview using GeoServer. However, when I add the layer to my Openlayers map (as well WFS as WMS), the entities change depending on the scale. Mostly it's the small multipolygons that are no longer visible. I've noticed that there are 3 zoom levels at which there's a toggle like on the GIF below.

[image]

I'd like to display all features on the map at all zoom levels. As for my Openlayers map, I haven't added any code related to the scale/zoom level. The strange thing is that all the other layers on my map that I've added in exactly the same way don't have this problem.

What could be the cause of this problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far and with which it's possible to reproduce described behavior, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.